# how to iterate over different kwargs?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I feel like this question must have been asked before but I failed to find it, sorry if that's the case!

I have a function with different arguments like:

```
def f(arg1, arg2, ...,argN, kw1=0, kw2=0, kw3=0):
    # some code ...
```

assuming I have my (compulsory) arguments defined:

```
arg1 = some_value_1
arg2 = some_value_2
...
argN = some_value_N
```

I want to condense some repetitive function calls like

```
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw1=1)
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw1=23)
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw2=456)
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw2=789)
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw3='a')
f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw3='b')
...
```

into something looking like:

```
for kw_def in [kw1=1, kw1=23, kw2=456, kw2=789, kw3='a', kw3='b',...]:
    f(arg1, arg2, ... argN, kw_def)
```

but syntactically correct. What's the right pythonic way of doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dictionaries:

```
for kw_def in [
    {'kw1': 1},
    {'kw1': 23},
    {'kw2': 456},
]:
    f(arg1, ..., argN, **kw_def)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [partial functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Assuming you have a function with this signature:

```
def f(arg1, arg2, arg3, kw1, kw2, kw3):
    pass
```

You could shorten calls that have common values for `arg1`, `arg2`, `kw1` and `kw2` like this:

```
from functools import partial
f_short = partial(f, 1, 2, kw1="A", kw2="B")
f_short(3, kw3="C")
```

This call to `f_short` would be equivalent to the direct call below:

```
f(1, 2, 3, kw1="A", kw2="B", kw3="C")
```